# Reshaping inputs to be fed to first layer in Keras

Tags: keras, neural-network

I am trying to implement multiple regression using Keras but the input to the first layer has dimension mismatch issue.

exact error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape [10, 2]
```

the `X_train` has `shape (6860, 2)`,  `y_train` has `shape (6860,)`, `batch_size=10`

First layer:

```
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 6))
```

How can I reshape the inputs?

Thanks!

Comment: `input_dim` is the number of dimensions that your data has - here you've specified 6 dimensions, but your input batch only has 2 dimensions. You might be better off specifying the `input_shape=(2)`, to which Keras will automatically add the batch dimension making it `(10, 2)`

Comment: Solves it! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, I've added it as an answer, please accept if it helped :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_dim` is the number of dimensions that your data has - here you've specified 6 dimensions, but your input batch only has 2 dimensions. You might be better off specifying the `input_shape=(2)`, to which Keras will automatically add the batch dimension making it (10, 2).